# Не переведена страница аналитики

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Не переведена [страница аналитики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics)

1) Не переведены месяцы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и на самом графике:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) На странице с источниками трафика не переведены:

- "Top Ten Referring Sites"
- На  диаграмме и легенде источников трафика: search, referring,
  direct.

3) Надпись в самом низу: "All data is derived from Google Analytics collected in the previous month"

**UPD:** так же на странице заголовок, который в браузере отображается, с маленькой буквы.

Comment: При получении привилегии первым делом вычитал текст и зарепортил ошибки. Одобряю ваш подход. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin стараюсь помогать по мере возможностей )

Comment: и "Делегат" заодно набивается. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin мелочь, а приятно =D

Comment: а в счет Сократа только один вопрос в день. Регулярность нужна. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin будем работать надо этим)

Comment: у меня 56 уже )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправлено всё, кроме:

- Стиля отображения даты. В модераторской статистике есть похожий выбор даты и там формат другой. Значит, и здесь такой возможен. 
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- search, referring, direct – этих строк [нет-в-transifex](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-transifex)